# Drawing shaded areas on map with Python's plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to draw some shaded areas on a map using [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-on-mapbox/). The coordinates are contained in a pandas dataframe where each cell shows a specific area to be plotted. A problem arises when I try to draw more than one area on the map - this is defined by `coordinates`:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# my test dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'names':['area1','area2','area3'], 'coords': 0})
df['coords'] = df['coords'].astype(object)
df.at[0,'coords'] = [[-73.606352888, 45.507489991], [-73.606133883, 45.50687600], [-73.617533258, 45.527512253], [-73.618074188, 45.526759105], [-73.618271651, 45.526500673], [-73.618446320, 45.526287943], [-73.620201713, 45.524298907], [-73.620775593, 45.523650879]]
df.at[1,'coords'] = [[-73.706352888, 45.507489991], [-73.706133883, 45.50687600], [-73.717533258, 45.527512253], [-73.718074188, 45.526759105], [-73.718271651, 45.526500673], [-73.718446320, 45.526287943], [-73.720201713, 45.524298907], [-73.720775593, 45.523650879]]
df.at[2,'coords'] = [[-73.606352888, 45.497489991], [-73.606133883, 45.49687600], [-73.617533258, 45.517512253], [-73.618074188, 45.516759105], [-73.618271651, 45.516500673], [-73.618446320, 45.516287943], [-73.620201713, 45.514298907], [-73.620775593, 45.513650879]]

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(mode = "markers", lon = [-73.605], lat = [45.51],))
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox = {'style': "stamen-terrain",
              'center': { 'lon': -73.6, 'lat': 45.5},
              'zoom': 12, 'layers': [{'source': {'type': "FeatureCollection",
                                                 'features': [{'type': "Feature",
                                                               'geometry': {'type': "MultiPolygon",
                                                                            'coordinates': [[df.coords[0],df.coords[1],df.coords[2]]]
#                                                                             'coordinates': [df.coords.tolist()]
                                                                           }
                                                              }]
                                                },
                                      'type': "fill", 'below': "traces", 'color': "royalblue"}]},
    margin = {'l':0, 'r':0, 'b':0, 't':0})
fig.show()
```

If I try `'coordinates': [df.coords.tolist()]` or `'coordinates': [[df.coords[0],df.coords[1],df.coords[2]]]`, only some areas are plotted. When I zoom out of the map, some of the areas disappear.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

How do I change the appearance of the shaded areas, eg. transparency?

How do I add labels to each shaded area (`area1`, `area2`, `area3`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each area, you should add a `Scattermapbox` trace. Here is how I would do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# my test dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'names':['area1','area2','area3'], 'coords': 0})
df['coords'] = df['coords'].astype(object)
df.at[0,'coords'] = [[-73.606352888, 45.507489991], [-73.606133883, 45.50687600], [-73.617533258, 45.527512253], [-73.618074188, 45.526759105], [-73.618271651, 45.526500673], [-73.618446320, 45.526287943], [-73.620201713, 45.524298907], [-73.620775593, 45.523650879]]
df.at[1,'coords'] = [[-73.706352888, 45.507489991], [-73.706133883, 45.50687600], [-73.717533258, 45.527512253], [-73.718074188, 45.526759105], [-73.718271651, 45.526500673], [-73.718446320, 45.526287943], [-73.720201713, 45.524298907], [-73.720775593, 45.523650879]]
df.at[2,'coords'] = [[-73.606352888, 45.497489991], [-73.606133883, 45.49687600], [-73.617533258, 45.517512253], [-73.618074188, 45.516759105], [-73.618271651, 45.516500673], [-73.618446320, 45.516287943], [-73.620201713, 45.514298907], [-73.620775593, 45.513650879]]

def get_close_coords(coords):
    c = np.zeros((len(coords) + 1, 2))
    c[:-1, :] = coords
    c[-1, :] = c[0, :]
    return c
    
fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(mode = "markers", lon = [-73.605], lat = [45.51]))

for i, c in enumerate(df.coords):
    coords = get_close_coords(c)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(lat=coords[:, 1], lon=coords[:, 0], mode="lines", fill="toself", name="Area %s" % i, opacity=0.4))

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox = {
        'style': "stamen-terrain",
        'center': {'lon': -73.6, 'lat': 45.5},
        'zoom': 12,
    },
    margin = {'l':0, 'r':0, 'b':0, 't':0})
fig.show()
```

Comment: thanks, can you please explain the purpose of `get_close_coords` function?

Comment: Let's consider `df.coords[0]`: it does have a start point and an end point, which are different. So, if I draw a line over `df.coords[0]` it will be an open line.`get_close_coords` simply copy the start point and place it as an end point, so the line will be closed. If you look carefully at one of filled areas, you will see the outer edge encompassing all points: this is the result of `get_close_coords`. If I didn't use it, you would see an "open" edge between the start and end point, which in my opinion is not nice to see.

Comment: also, in the line `fig.add_trace(..., name="Area %s" % i, ...)` is there a way to remove the coordinates label and display the full string for `name`? If `name` is a long string, the label only shows the first 12 elements of the string and then `...`

Comment: You would have to play with hover data. Take a look at this doc page: https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/

Comment: thanks, it works if I add `fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(..., hovertemplate = " <br>", ...))`